# java cli running indicator

Tags: java, command-line-interface

I want some ascii characters periodically changing to indicate my CLI program is running, like -|\/-|/.... The old character is replaced by the new, which looks like an animation. Is there any library approaching that?

Kejia

Comment: Hi all, I don't have time to test the advices. I will give you feedback as I finish. BTW: for a costly computation, it's a bad idea to show the stupid progressing symbols in CLI :-)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the [carriage return(CR)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) character ('\r' in java) to do this. I would do it this way (assuming you are doing the animation at the beginning of the row):

My solution (Test.java):

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            System.out.print("\\");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.print("\r|");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.print("\r/");
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest idea: try replace all console (rows & cols) with new view (frame) of your animation.

Answer (score 0):

I once wrote a test program and part of it worked like curl/wget to download a file. To print the progress I just used `System.err.print(n); System.err.print('\r');` which moves the cursor to the start of the line ready for the next progress update. But in your case you could probably print each one of `"\\\b"` `"-\b"` `"/\b"` (`\b` is backspace) in order repetitively to get the spinning effect.

Answer (score 0):

In Scala:

```
"-|\\/-|/".toCharArray ().foreach {c =>  print ("\b" + c); Thread.sleep (250); }
```

Analog, but more Code in Java, but not tested:

```
for (c : "-|\\/-|/".toCharArray ()) 
{
    System.out.print ("\b" + c); 
    Thread.sleep (250); 
}
```

Comment: Obviously, you have to put this inside a while(true) { .... }